# jQuery get user's Skype Contacts

Tags: jquery

Is there a jQuery command to retrieve the user's Skype contacts?
I'm building an internal "newsfeed" page for work, and I'd like to make a share button with email and Skype. The Skype button would first get the user's contacts, they select a contact, then the code would put that into a variable that I can then use in the command to open a convo with a link to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach is to use share buttons, it is easier to implement. see skypes website for their share button:

- https://www.skype.com/en/developer/create-share-buttons/
  (unfortunately the link is broken on my side)

or you may use another sharing service like addthis to support multiple share programs:

- https://www.addthis.com/blog/2017/05/04/skype-share-button/#.XLlV20xuKkw